# Django DateFromToRange filter seems does not work

Tags: django, django-filter, django-filters

I have two models with a simple relation as below:

## models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class PersonSession(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True,
                                    blank=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='person_sessions')
```

## views.py

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    start_time = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(
        name='person_sessions__start_time',
        distinct=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'start_time')

class PersonList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Person.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PersonSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend)
    filter_class = PersonFilter
```

As it is shown I want to use [DateFromToRangeFilter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#datefromtorangefilter) and I expect that I get api such this:

```
api/persons?start_time_before=2018-04-20&start_time_after=2018-04-18
```

But this does not work at all. It seems as stated in this [post](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters/issues/125), there is an error with implementation of this type of filter but solution in the post does not work for me because I would get two inner join and get completely different results as I expected.

Comment: api/persons?start_time_0=2018-04-20&start_time_1=2018-04-18

Comment: This url is like it was used at the post I mentioned,  but I have two problems with that, first It has not explained in documentation directly and second It is very vague and I do not understand what is before and what is after because both of them has a strange results for me.

Comment: @amankumar Using _0 for gt and _1 for lt this works as expected, but as I mentioned before this is a vague and improper name for filtering date and I hope to find a way to use better name conventions.

Comment: Put your filter class in a filters.py file, not in your views.py file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by creating a custom filter method:

```py
start_date = filters.CharFilter(
    method='filter_date_range'
)

def filter_date_range(self, queryset, name, value):
    filter_dict = {}
    splitted = value.split(',')

    if len(splitted) != 2:
        return queryset

    start = parse_date(splitted[0])
    end = parse_date(splitted[1])

    filter_dict[name + '__gte'] = start if start else datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
    filter_dict[name + '__lt'] = end if end else datetime.date(2200, 1, 1)

    return queryset.filter(**filter_dict)
```

SQL:

```
"app"."start_date" < 2018 - 01 - 10 AND "app"."start_date" >= 2000 - 01 - 01
```

This can be improved, but at least it does a direct check in the WHERE clause and having comparing the first value with T1 and the second value with T2.

Answer (score 1):

I have the similar case. Maybe for someone it will be helpful.

```
class Task(ComputedFieldsModel):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tco_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

class TaskRangeStatisticsView(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TaskRangeStatisticsSerializer
    filterset_class = TaskRangeStatisticsBackend

    def get(self,request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()) \
            .annotate(date=TruncDay('created_at')) \
            .values("date") \
            .annotate(finished_count=Count('tco_at'),created_count=Count('created_at'),in_progress_count=Count('in_progress_at')) \
            .order_by("-date")
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class TaskRangeStatisticsBackend(df_filters.FilterSet):
    date = df_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter(field_name="created_at")
    # 'date_after': '2016-01-01', 'date_before': '2016-02-01'

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ["date"]
```

Now query like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test_tasks_statistics/?date_after=2021-06-01&date_before=2021-06-04` works fine

Answer (score -1):

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
      start_time_before = DateFilter(name='person_sessions__start_time',lookup_expr=('gt'),) 
      start_time_after = DateFilter(name='person_sessions__start_time',lookup_expr=('lt'))
```

if you want same url, you can use this class.

Comment: heads up! This actually wont work bc of the way the 2 filters create a join across the many to many. What this actually translates to is "persons with a session before x OR a session after x". If there are 2 sessions associated with the user you can replicate this issue. It's bc the 2 filters independently join the table in.